# Does azurite support CloudTable?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-emulator, azurite

Does azurite mac support local emulation of `CloudTable`? azurite works fine for an `EventGridTrigger` but not `CloudTable`.

using an azure function to work with azure storage:

```
[FunctionName("...")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger ...,
            [Table("Name", "PK", "RK")] ...,
            [Table("Name")] CloudTable tableOut)
```

and running azurite before starting the function in Visual Studio For Mac:

```
azurite -s -l /tmp/azurite -d /tmp/azurite/debug.log
```

the function fails to start with the error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Can't bind Table to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudTable works and Azurite table service is now in preview, starting with version 3.12.00: https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/releases/tag/v3.12.0

A nice way to avoid cluttering your repositories with annoying Azurite files is to run Azurite in a docker container (see https://github.com/Azure/Azurite#DockerHub).

```
docker run -p 10000:10000 -p 10001:10001 -p 10002:10002 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the latest [azurite](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite) doesn't support Tables:

> V3 currently only supports Blob and Queue service, please use V2 for
> Table service for the time being.

```
sudo npm install -g azurite@2.7.0
```

but that doesn't work either.